# Calculate how much air will cool from an amount of ice?

Tags: thermodynamics, water

So, there are $3kg$ of ice at $-18$ degrees Celsius and $50kg$ of air at $30$ degrees Celsius. I need to calculate how much the air will cool by the time the ice reaches its temperature.

I thought I solved it, but I get an absurd answer.

First, how much energy the ice needs to get to 0 degrees:

$$Q_1 = 18 \cdot 3 \cdot 2,1 = 113,4 kJ$$

How much energy it needs to melt:

$$Q_2 = 3 \cdot 334 = 1002 kJ$$

How much energy the ice (now water) needs to get to 30 degrees. I ignored the change in the temperature of the air, since that would result in a quadratic equation and I thought that it is insignificant.

$$Q_3 = 30 \cdot 3 \cdot 4,2 = 378 kJ$$

$$Q = Q_1 + Q_2 + Q_3 = 1493,4 kJ$$

Now I need to divide that by the specific heat capacity of air (which I assumed to be 1) and the mass of the air.

$$\Delta t = Q / (1 \cdot 50) = 1493,3 / 50 = 29,868^{\circ}$$

To me this is a very surprising answer and I don't think its correct. Also, its almost $30$ degrees, which would mean that with a bit more ice the air will cool down to less than 0 degrees, so not all the ice will melt.

Did I make a mistake somewhere or is this just another instance of faulty intuition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation of the heats up to the melting point are correct and useful. If we devide that heat by the heat capacity of the air and the mass of the air, we obtain 22.308K. This is the amount by which the air's temperature has dropped by the time the ice is completely molten and at 0°C.
Now we can continue to calculate the final temperature by the following equation:
$$m_{water}\cdot c_{water}\cdot \Delta T=m_{air}\cdot c_{air} \cdot (30-22.308-\Delta T)$$

In other words, the amount of heat that is still available to warm up the water equals the amount of heat that can be taken from 50kg of ~7.7°C hot air and that only down to the mixing temperature.

So your mistake lies in assuming arbitrarily that the water will get heated up to 30°C. Solve above equation to find the real value.

Note that in your approach, the water would become warmer than the surrounding air! This would lead the air to warm up afterwards, if it were to happen, and can thus not be a final equilibrium state.

I did not check the numerical values of your constants.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that that part was not correct, when I wrote it. However, I did it that way because originally I thought that it will be pretty close to 30 degrees. It is just that I find it weird that a couple kilos of ice can cool down a room by 20-30 degrees. BTW even your calculation is not completely correct as the air's temperature will be slightly bellow 7,7 degrees by the time the system reaches equilibrium.

Comment: This is because phase changes take a comparably high amount of energy. For fun, you can try to calculate how much water at 100°C and vapor at 100°C can warm up e.g. a bit of milk at fridge temperature. That is one of the reasons for using vapor to warm the milk for cappucino :D

Comment: Yeah, I made an excell file with which to calculate any such things and damn, the difference is nearly an order of magnitude.